# How can I open a GTK/QT program remotely through SSH?

Tags: linux, ssh, raspberry-pi, raspbian, remote

I have a Raspberry Pi 4, and I want to open a GTK app up, through SSH. However, whenever I try to start up this GTK app, it gives the following error:

```bsh
_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

It gives a similar error on every GTK application, and I understand that if I use SSH on a local machine, the shell would assume that I want to open it on that host.

Is there a way to open an app through SSH remotely?

Comment: What SSH client are you using, on which platform?

Comment: It is unclear whether you want that app to display itself on target machine or yours.

Answer (score 1):

`ssh -X` *username@raspberry_pi*

`-X` tells ssh to forward X11 back to the calling system (your desktop)

Comment: Unfortunately, it still says the same thing, when I try to open up *Thonny* or my *OpenCV* script. However, when I use that command I get this line when logging in: `xset:  unable to open display ""`. Any idea?

Comment: Must be capital `X`.    if you're doing that what system are you SSHing from?